# Intel 5G solution 5000 of HP dragonfly elite G3 does not work on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04

Tags: drivers, hp, modem

I recently bought the labtop HP dragonfly elite G3.
It has 5G Modem Intel 5G solution 5000.
Windows 11 well support the modem and the modem work well.
See the below capture.

[Hardware list on Windows 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqn6Y.png)

I also installed Ubuntu 20.04 and even 22.04.
But Ubuntu does not detect the modem (also sound driver.. but it doesn't matter).
I tried to solve the related issues by referring to them, but failed.
update kernel, check hardware list using lsusb and lspci, etc.

I guess for now the drivers for this modem have not been updated in Ubuntu yet.

Where can I request to an update for this modem or check the support list or plan for this modem?